# Retrieving nested dictionaries in class instances

Tags: python, python-3.x, dictionary

I have several classes which have dictionaries as attributes. These dictionaries store instances of other classes. The lower/nested classes also have dictionaries as attributes as well.

Currently I am writing full loops, with breaks, to retrieve the nested values. Problem is that I need to do several processes/filters on the nested dictionaries so it seems computationally expensive as well as it leading to ugly, spaghetti-like code. What I would like to do is be able to access the nested items, update the items (in-place), and continue on.. Is there a way to do this?

Example code (let's assume you might wear several socks in each shoe and have several colored toes):

```
class Shoe:
    def __init__(self):
        self.socks = {} # this contains instances of socks

class Sock:
    def __init__(self):
        self.toes = {} # this contains instances of toes
        self.color = 'green'

class Toe:
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = 'blue'
```

Now I want to look inside the `Shoe` instance and retrieve/update all `Sock` instances which are green and have `blue` `Toe`s. Then update the `Sock`/`Toe` instances I retrieved so that when I access the shoe later the values have changed.

All help is appreciated!

Comment: Would a database structure work for you? Because this is one of the main reasons databases exist.

Comment: I don't think so - but I could very likely be wrong. This is for processing Computer Vision/Deep Learning tasks. Once the task is processed then I convert all this to JSON and send it over to the database. Isn't there latency for making db calls? (can't have latency).

Comment: I guess I should say, the latency of calling the db, and reconstructing the objects, needs to be less than the current nested loops to make it worthwhile.

Comment: How many attributes such as color do you have? If it is a single one, you might want to build a dictionary of `color: instances`. But if there are many this solution might be too slow. About the db, if your data is relatively small (say a few thousand entries), maintaining an in memory database would not induce (much) latency. (see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#sqlite3.connect) for an example)

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you can use a list instead of obj

```
class Shoe:
    def __init__(self):
        self.socks = [] # this contains instances of socks

class Sock:
    def __init__(self):
        self.toes = [] # this contains instances of toes
        self.color = 'green'

class Toe:
    def __init__(self):
        self.color = 'blue'

toe = Toe()

socks = Sock()
socks.toes.append(toe)

shoes = Shoe()
shoes.socks.append(socks)
```

then you can iterate as you want

```
for s in shoes.socks: # s becomes in a list of sock
    for t in s.toes: # t becomes in a list of toes
        for color in t:
            print(color)
```

or maybe i do not understand what you really need.

greeting

Comment: Dang. Right after I posted this question I thought of using lists then I left the post up in hopes that that was not the answer.  I think you are right. I am going to leave it open for about an hour to see if anyone else has a solution I am not thinking of. Then mark yours as the answer.

Comment: @DavidAlford how is this different than what you'd do with the `dict`s?